# Django Celery Settings Import Issue

Tags: python, django, celery

Im trying to create a celery file and run it via ..

```
celery -A myapp worker -l info
```

However Im getting the error,

```
  File "/production/pythonenv/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/configurations/base.py", line 30, in __new__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(install_failure)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: django-configurations settings importer wasn't correctly installed. Please use one of the starter functions to install it as mentioned in the docs: http://django-configurations.readthedocs.org/
```

Here are the config/files,

**Tree**

(run from the project rool via 'tree myapp/ config/')

```
config/
|-- __init__.py
|-- __init__.pyc
|-- celery.py
|-- settings.py
|-- urls.py
|-- wsgi.py  
myapp/
|-- __init__.py
|-- __init__.pyc
|-- celery.py
|-- helper.py
|-- models.pyc
|-- serializers.py
|-- views.py
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os,sys,
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

sys.path.append('/prod/project/')
sys.path.append('/prod/')

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_CONFIGURATION', 'Local')

app = Celery('myapp.celery.celery')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS, related_name='tasks')
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to http://django-configurations.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/#celery you may need to add in your `celery.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_CONFIGURATION', 'Local')

from configurations import importer
importer.install()

app = Celery('myapp.celery.celery')
```

Comment: Yoooo this just saved me after a ton of googling/troubleshooting. Thanks a ton!